# AngularJS Filter expression replacing with variable instead

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a table object and I want to filter out a particular "index" row using filter function as shown below.
However, `$controller.expression` is not working out.

```
IF `$controller.expression = "3";
```

It would work. But not

```
$controller.expression = "3,4";
$controller.expression = [3,4];
```

---

```
$scope.dataToBeTransfer = $scope.myDataTable.filter(function (el)
{
   return el.index== $controller.expression;
});
```

So how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use an array you need to loop through to see if el.index is included in the array. This is probably the easiest way to do it from the given code:

```
$scope.dataToBeTransfer = $scope.myDataTable.filter(function (el) {
  return $controller.expression.includes(el.index);
});
```

Comment: nice! Thank you so much from the bottom of my heart